# How do I get a formatted display for this program? (Beginner)

Tags: java, for-loop, multidimensional-array

So, I have this piece of code here

```
for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
  for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
    System.out.print(newImage[i][j]);
  }
}
```

Which gives me the following output -

```
17715613511813411198998282899264799679
```

What I want to actually do is print the array newImage so that it looks like the following -

```
177 156 135 118
134 111 98 99
82 82 89 92
64 79 96 79
```

Note : The dimensions of newImage are not known and can be an array of any size. That's why I am using a for loop to print all values of it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
  for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
    System.out.print(newImage[i][j]+" ");
  }
  System.out.println("");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

- After printing each number, do `System.out.print(' ');`
- After printing each line, do `System.out.println();`

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by adding two line into your code

1. After printing each number add `System.out.print(' ');`
2. After printing each line add `System.out.println();`

For example your code should be like this

```
for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) 
{
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) 
    {
        System.out.print(newImage[i][j]);
        System.out.print(' ');
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```